# In XSLT 2.0, why is there no fn:decode-for-uri?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, urlencode

I have a URI encoded string in XML but can't decode it using xslt.

There is a [fn:encode-for-uri](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-encode-for-uri) to encode the string

But no **decode-for-uri** to decode.

1. Is there a function I have missed?
2. If not, why does it not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael Kay answered this question [here](http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/200911/msg00298.html):

> No there's no such function.
>
> As a matter of interest, what's the use case?
>
> I think the only reasons it's not there are (a) absence of a use case,
>   and (b) difficulty in the detail of specifying it: what do you do for
>   example with percent signs that aren't followed by two hex digits.

(b) seems easy enough to solve: either say behavior is implementation dependent, or say the processor will throw a runtime error. But maybe there's more to this question than I'm aware of.

Update: [This follow-up post](http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/200911/msg00300.html) (in the same thread as linked above) shows an XSLT implementation of a function to decode percent-encoded (unreserved) characters.